# Python traversing through different XML tags

Tags: python, xml, parsing

I have an XML file in the following format:

```
<commands>
  <command name = "">
  <data byte=""></data>
  </command>
</commands>

<registers>
  <register name = "">
  <mask name =""></mask>
</registers>
```

Before adding the register tags, I could traverse through the document with no problems using:

```
for command_data_name in root.findall('command'):
    if (command_data_name.get('major') == major_bits and command_data_name.get('minor') == minor_bits):
        command_name = command_data_name.get('name')
```

but now I get

```
xml.etree.ElementTree.ParseError: junk after document element.
```

Obviously caused my by integration of the register tags. How is this supposed to look if I want to grab the register information?

```
  <registers>

    <register name="Command">
      <bits major_mask="0xFF00000000", right_shift="32", left_shift="0"></bits>
      <bits minor_mask="0xFF0000000000", right_shift="40", left_shift="0"></bits>
      <bits doorbell_mask="0x1000000000000", right_shift="48", left_shift="0"></bits>
      <bits sequence_mask="0xF000000000000000", right_shift="63", left_shift="0"></bits>
    </register>

    <register name="Status">
      <bits mb_comp_mask="0x1", right_shift="0", left_shift="0"></bits>
      <bits nonce_mask="0x2", right_shift="1", left_shift="0"></bits>
      <bits bos_mask="0xFF", right_shift="3", left_shift="0"></bits>
      <bits status_code_mask="0xFF00", right_shift="12", left_shift="0"></bits>
    </register>

  </registers>
```

Comment: Is that the complete xml ?

Comment: I have a ton of the same thing replicated, so basically, yes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each XML Document should only have 1 root element , but the document you should above have multiple root elements - `<commands>` and `<registers>` . From [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root_element) -

> Each XML document has exactly one single root element. It encloses all the other elements and is therefore the sole parent element to all the other elements. ROOT elements are also called PARENT elements.

This is what is causing the error -

```
xml.etree.ElementTree.ParseError: junk after document element
```

The easiest way to fix this would be to wrap up everything inside a single root element , but the real fix would be to consider how you want your xml to be structured , and structure it accordingly (so that it only has 1 root element).

---

Another issue is the `,` in the xml , you do not need comma in the xml elements, remove them and it should work. Example of comma -

```
<bits major_mask="0xFF00000000", right_shift="32", left_shift="0"></bits>
                               ^                 ^
                               comma causing issue
```

Comment: Hm, so I tried to wrap everything between <information></information> and it still doesn't work.

Comment: xml.etree.ElementTree.ParseError: not well-formed (invalid token)

Comment: Update the question with the xml you are getting that error for.

Comment: added the bit that is screwing it up.

Comment: AH, I don't think I am supposed to have commas!

Comment: Updated - Another issue is the , in the xml , you do not need comma in the xml elements, remove them and it should work

Comment: Sorry, wasn't at my computer.